# Problem adding check box to dialog box

Tags: android

Hi I’ve been having some difficulty adding a checkbox to a dialog window. The dialog contains instructions and I don’t want it to show every time. I want it to stop showing when the user checks the checkbox and clicks ok. A moment code I get a force close because of the on click listener for the check box but not sure how else to implement it.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Here's the code

```
     private void dialog(){   
     final SharedPreferences settings = this.getSharedPreferences("MyApp",0);
     boolean stillrun=settings.getBoolean("stillrun",true);

     if (stillrun) {        
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(Zoom.this);
       dialog.setContentView(R.layout.info);       
       dialog.setTitle("Using the zoom function");
       dialog.setCancelable(true);
       TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.text);      
       text.setText(R.string.zoomtext);         
       Button button = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.buttonClose);


       button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(View v) {                             
       dialog.cancel(); 
           }
      });


       CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
       checkbox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(View v) {

           if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
            SharedPreferences.Editor e = settings.edit();
              e.putBoolean("stillrun",false);
              e.commit();
           } 
        }
    });  

    dialog.show();



}
```

Answer (score 0):

You read the property from "stillrun" and write to the property "firstrun" - is this what you want?

Comment: Thank you well spotted, do have any idea how I can resolve the force close issue. Its to do with the check boxes on click listener but I don't know how else to implement it in a dialog. Thanks Again!